# vb.net How to overwrite the text in a combobox after the dropdownclosed event

Tags: vb.net, combobox, overwrite

I created this piece of code to illustrate the idea, it uses a combobox and a textbox

```
Private Sub ComboBox2_DropDown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox2.DropDown
    ComboBox2.Items.Clear()
    ComboBox2.Items.Add("0001 | Apple")
    ComboBox2.Items.Add("0002 | Pear")
    ComboBox2.Items.Add("0003 | Banana")
    ComboBox2.Items.Add("0004 | Pineapple")
    ComboBox2.Items.Add("0005 | Cherry")
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox2_DropDownClosed(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox2.DropDownClosed
    Dim selecteditem As String = ComboBox2.Items(ComboBox2.SelectedIndex)
    ComboBox2.Text = Strings.Left(selecteditem,4)
    TextBox2.Text = Strings.Left(selecteditem,4)
End Sub
```

When I select an item from the combobox what happens is that the combobox keeps showing the whole string while the textbox only shows the first 4 characters.

How can I overwrite the combobox text after I close the combobox?

*** edit ***
I tried a combo of the solutions but ran into a problem because the data was bound to a datasource so it's not possible to change the item.
This is the new code:

```
Private Sub ComboBox2_DropDown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox2.DropDown
    SQL.ExecQuery($"select ID, Name, RTRIM(ID + ' | ' + Name) as SingleColumn from GCCTEST.dbo.tblFruit")
    ComboBox2.DataSource = SQL.DBDT
    ComboBox2.DisplayMember = "SingleColumn"
End Sub
Private Sub ComboBox2_DropDownClosed(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox2.DropDownClosed
    ComboBox2.DisplayMember = "ID"
    ComboBox2.SelectedIndex = 0
End Sub
```

Now I only need to have the 0 be the index I chose...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work.
If not necessary, don't populate the combobox on every drop-down, instead call the `FillComboBox`-method when loading the `Form`.

```
Private Sub FillComboBox()
    SQL.ExecQuery($"select ID, Name, RTRIM(ID + ' | ' + Name) as SingleColumn from GCCTEST.dbo.tblFruit")
    ComboBox2.DataSource = SQL.DBDT
    ComboBox2.DisplayMember = "ID" 
    ComboBox2.ValueMember = "ID"
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox2_DropDown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox2.DropDown
    Me.ComboBox2.DisplayMember = "SingleColumn"
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox2_SelectionChangeCommitted(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox2.SelectionChangeCommitted
    Dim selV As Object = Me.ComboBox2.SelectedValue

    Me.TextBox2.Text = CStr(selV)
    Me.ComboBox2.DisplayMember = "ID"

    'Set the current value again, otherwise the combobox will always display the first item
    Me.ComboBox2.SelectedValue = selV
End Sub
```

Comment: This is also a working solution which I actually prefer. It is more in line with what I already have. Thanks.

Comment: I am keeping the FillComboBox outside the form load event by the way. In this case it's not a problem but with a few comboboxes and a lot of data in the comboboxes it takes extra seconds to load the form.

Answer (score 1):

I used a few properties and .net `String.SubString` method instead of the old vb6 `Strings.Left`.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_DropDownClosed(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.DropDownClosed
        Dim SelectedString As String = ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString
        Dim ChangedString As String = SelectedString.Substring(0, 4)
        Dim index As Integer = ComboBox1.SelectedIndex
        ComboBox1.Items(index) = ChangedString
End Sub
```

You can fill your combo box one by one to avoid binding problems as follows...

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_DropDown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.DropDown
        Using cn As New SqlConnection("Your connection string")
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand("Select ID, Name From tblFruit;", cn)
                cn.Open()
                Using dr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                    ComboBox1.BeginUpdate()
                    While dr.Read
                        ComboBox1.Items.Add(dr(0).ToString & " | " & dr(1).ToString)
                    End While
                    ComboBox1.EndUpdate()
                End Using
            End Using
    End Using
```

Comment: This works for the given example, but in reality the combobox is bound to a datasource which gives a problem like: Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource property is set

Comment: @MiguelTerlaak Instead of binding the datasource, you could create a sub that populates the combobox instead. Dont forget to use SuspendLayout and ResumeLayout at the beginning and end of the sub to improve performance.

Comment: I am populating the combobox with a sql query which to my knowledge automatically binds the datasourse. I added that new piece of code at the bottom of the question.

Comment: @MiguelTerlaak I have added code to demonstrate filling the combo box without binding. As suggested by @David Wilson, I used `.BeginUpdate` and `.EndUpdate`

Comment: @Mary Thank you, this is a working solution. Only need to add a combobox1.Items.Clear() otherwise the combobox keeps filling up and a check on the combobox1.selectedindex > -1 in case the user don't select anything at the first instance.

Comment: @MiguelTerlaak If this answer works, please accept as answer with the check mark (tick mark) to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this graphical problem putting a `Label` in your `Form` and moving it over your `ComboBox`.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Me.Label1.AutoSize = False
    Me.Label1.BackColor = Me.ComboBox1.BackColor
    Me.Label1.Location = New Point(Me.ComboBox1.Location.X + 1, Me.ComboBox1.Location.Y + 1)
    Me.Label1.Size = New Size(Me.ComboBox1.Width - 18, Me.ComboBox1.Height - 2)

    Me.ComboBox1.Items.Add("0001 | Apple")
    Me.ComboBox1.Items.Add("0002 | Pear")
    Me.ComboBox1.Items.Add("0003 | Banana")
    Me.ComboBox1.Items.Add("0004 | Pineapple")
    Me.ComboBox1.Items.Add("0005 | Cherry")

End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged

    Me.Label1.Text = Trim(Me.ComboBox1.SelectedItem.Split("|")(0))

End Sub
```

Please note that:

- you can populate your `ComboBox` a single time during `Form` load event
- you can use `SelectedIndexChanged` instead of `DropDown` and `DropDownClosed` event
- if this is not a graphical problem please give a look at [`DisplayMember`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`ValueMember`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.valuemember(v=vs.110).aspx) properties